# URL substring matching regular expression?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Suppose I only want user to type in url starts with http://www.google.com
What is the regular expression for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the substring from 0 to the length of `http://www.google.com` and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use a regex, you might want to consider using the [URI library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/) that comes with Ruby. It's made to take apart and build URLs, is well tested, and less error-prone than trying to reinvent the same functionality.

```
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse('http://www.google.com/path/to/page.html?a=1&b=2')
url.scheme # => "http"
url.host   # => "www.google.com"
url.path   # => "/path/to/page.html"
url.query  # => "a=1&b=2"
```

If that's not good enough, the [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/) gem is even more capable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/\Ahttp:\/\/www\.google\.com(.*)?\Z/

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "http://www.google.com" =~ /\Ahttp:\/\/www\.google\.com(.*)?\Z/
=> 0 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "http://www.google.com/foobar" =~ /\Ahttp:\/\/www\.google\.com(.*)?\Z/
=> 0 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > $1
=> "/foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a convenient start_with? method for this. If it's just a static string, no regular expression is needed.

`url.start_with?("http://www.google.com")`